# Having trouble understanding "do...while" loops

Tags: c, do-while

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int start_size;
    do
    {
        start_size = get_int("Start size (an integer at least greater than or equal to 9): ");
    }while (start_size < 9);

    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    int end_size;
    do
    {
        end_size = get_int("End size (an integer at least greater than or equal to start size): ");
    }while (end_size < start_size);

    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int years = 0;
    int n = start_size;
    do
    {
        n = n + (n / 3) - (n / 4);
        years++;
    }while (n < end_size);


    // TODO: Print number of years
    printf("Years: %i\n", years);
}
```

This is from CS50 Lab 1. My code handles all test fine until we have the same start and end size.

Obviously if we have the same start and end size, we should get "Years: 0", since we should only be running the do-while loop if the start size is less than the end size. But when we run the code with the same start and end size we get, "Years: 1". Why? Thanks!

Comment: unlike `while (condition)  { ... } `, `do { ... } while (condition)` will run at least one time.  The condition is tested _after_ execution .  your program has 3 `do/while` loops.  The first two should prompt _at least once_ for inputs, but the final loop shouldn't run _at least once_ so it should be a `while` loop, not a `do while`.

Answer (score 3):

> … we should only be running the do-while loop if the start size is less than the end size.

No, a `do … while` loop **always** enters the body of the loop and tests the condition only at the end of each iteration.

That is why it is written with the body first and the condition at the end, so it visually shows you the body executes first and then the condition is tested. A `while` loop is written with the condition first, and it tests the condition first and then, if the condition is satisfied, enters the body.

If you want the test first, write a `while` loop, not a `do … while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The do..while loop executes at least one time, even if the condition isn't accomplished, because the condition is at the end. I recommend to change the last do..while loop with a while loop. By doing that, you guarantee that the loop is not executed if the condition is not accomplished:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // TODO: Prompt for start size
    int start_size;
    do
    {
        start_size = get_int("Start size (an integer at least greater than or equal to 9): ");
    }while (start_size < 9);

    // TODO: Prompt for end size
    int end_size;
    do
    {
        end_size = get_int("End size (an integer at least greater than or equal to start size): ");
    }while (end_size < start_size);

    // TODO: Calculate number of years until we reach threshold
    int years = 0;
    int n = start_size;
    while (n < end_size)
    {
        n = n + (n / 3) - (n / 4);
        years++;
    }


    // TODO: Print number of years
    printf("Years: %i\n", years);
}
```

Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm
*"A do...while loop is similar to a while loop, except the fact that it is guaranteed to execute at least one time."*

Answer (score -1):

In this do-while loop

```
int years = 0;
int n = start_size;
do
{
    n = n + (n / 3) - (n / 4);
    years++;
}while (n < end_size);
```

the variable `years` is incremented at least one time in the first iteration of the loop independent on the condition of the loop that is checked after executing the body of the loop.

So the variable `years` always will have a value that is greater than `0`.

Try to change the do-while loop to while loop as for example

```
while (n < end_size)
{
    n = n + (n / 3) - (n / 4);
    years++;
}
```

In this case the condition of the loop will be checked before the body of the loop will get the control.

The difference between the while loop and the do-while loop is that the body of the do-while loop always initially gets the control because the condition of the loop is checked after executing the body of the loop.